# Ordenar una tabla en el que el indice de orden sea un valor String

Tags: php, html

Estoy realizando una pagina web en la que agrupa la información de un juego a cada jugador. Está información contiene el rango de la cuenta y los puntos, rango es Bronce, plata etc. Los datos los tengo en una tabla y quiero que se ordenen de mayor rango a menor pero no se como hacerlo.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8AX3.jpg
(esto es como tengo la tabla ahora mismo pero no se ordenarlo.)

Añado el codigo del th :
    echo "";

```
                    if ($rank[0][tier] != Null ){
                            if ($rank[1][QUEUETYPE] == "RANKED_FLEX_SR" ){
                                $soloq=0;

                            }else{
                                $soloq=1;


                            }

                            echo "<img style='vertical-align:middle;height:32px;width:32px;border-radius:32px' src=$imagen></img> ".$summoner[name]." (Nivel  ".$summoner[summonerLevel].") · ".$rank[$soloq][tier]." ".$rank[$soloq][rank]." [".$rank[$soloq][leaguePoints]." LP] W:<span style=color:green>".$rank[$soloq][wins]."</span> L:<span style=color:#950000>".$rank[$soloq][losses]."</span>";

                    }else{
                    echo "<img style='vertical-align:middle;height:32px;width:32px;border-radius:32px' src=$imagen></img> ".$summoner[name]." (Nivel  ".$summoner[summonerLevel].") · UNRANKED";
                    }
                    echo "</th>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Para reordenar arrays multidimensionales puedes usar esto:

```
<?php

    $users[] = array('name' => 'Sergio', 'age' => 22);
    $users[] = array('name' => 'Carlos', 'age' => 29);
    $users[] = array('name' => 'Iván', 'age' => 24);
    $users[] = array('name' => 'Jorge', 'age' => 21);
    $users[] = array('name' => 'Dani', 'age' => 25);
    $users[] = array('name' => 'Jose', 'age' => 27);
    $users[] = array('name' => 'David', 'age' => 19);
    $users[] = array('name' => 'Esteban', 'age' => 35);


    foreach ($users as $key => $row) {
        $aux[$key] = $row['age'];
    }


    array_multisort($aux, SORT_ASC, $users);


    foreach ($users as $key => $row) {
        echo $row['name'].' '.$row['age'].'<br/>';
    }
 ?>
```

> Fuente: https://www.jose-aguilar.com/blog/multidimensional-array-sort/
>   PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-multisort.php

Luego lo pintas.